# Laravel 4 ORM find by columns array

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4

Im learining Laravel 4 now, my company is updating and changing frameworks so i've got a question regarding its ORM/QueryBuilder/Whaterver...

Im wondering if its possible to use something like

```
Users::find(array(
    'role_id' => 2,
    'active' => 1
))
```

Thats basicly find by 2 columns. I DO NOT want to do something like this:

```
Users->where(...)->where(...)->get()
```

i would like the flexibility of an array.

Comment: It does raise the question of why you DO NOT want to do it using a perfectly sensible syntax.... do you have a valid  technical reason for avoiding the fluent interface style, or is this just personal preference (you don't like fluent interfaces or the readability that they provide)

Comment: realy its about the flexiability of the array, as mentioned in the post. i can add and remove parameters based on preference, i could basicly do the same with where(...), but thats just my own preference.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you creating a wrapper method that accepts an array and builds the where from that.... I've actually done that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from an OOP stand point, the later option is acctualy much nicer because it improves the readability.

You might benefit from using Laravels query builder (http://laravel.com/docs/queries), where you would not directly query the model itself.